# Parameters of SGDClassifier in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am kind of new to machine learning and I am running sample code from a book about machine learning, the code I am trying to run is here:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
clf = SGDClassifier(loss='log', random_state=1)
```

but when I call partial_fit() I get the error below:

The 'loss' parameter of SGDClassifier must be a str among {'hinge', 'modified_huber', 'huber', 'squared_error', 'epsilon_insensitive', 'squared_epsilon_insensitive', 'perceptron', 'squared_hinge', 'log_loss'}. Got 'log' instead.

can anyone help me with this.

Thank you.

Looking at the documentation, 'log' is a valid parameter.

Comment: Obviously, the documentation & the code disagree, and the code insists you choose one of the strings listed.  What other kind of "help" were you looking for?

Comment: ***"Looking at the documentation, 'log' is a valid parameter."*** What docs? Are you talking about your book? That's not documentation. The actual docs do not list `log` as a valid option for `loss`: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use 'log_loss' for the loss parameter, It should solve your problem.